# How to make list from this in python?

Tags: python, list

```
source = [{'address': 15620, 'street': 490}, {'address': 10180, 'street': 2187}, {'address': 10190, 'street': 670}, {'address': 20900, 'street': 572}, {'address': 8190, 'street': 1103}, {'address': 43110, 'street': 225}, {'address': 24780, 'street': 1465}, {'address': 50130, 'street': 249},]
```

I want to make a list like this. Please help me.
Thanks.

```
result = (15620, 10180, 10190, 20900, 8190, 43110, 24780, 50130)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to get the 'address' key from each dictionary in your source list:

```
result = [ d['address'] for d in source ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below using `get()`

```
k=[]
for i in source:
    k.append(i.get("address", ""))
```

k will give you the output you are looking for.